# Oracle array gives undefined variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am fairly new to Oracle and I have been googling this for the whole day.

I declared some arrays in a stored proc in Oracle using the code below

```
procedure process_shipping_order (i_shor_id in x_shipping_order.shor_id%type, o_error_text out varchar2)

is
type t_numbercoll is table of number index by pls_integer;
type t_varchar2coll is table of varchar2 (100) index by pls_integer;
tv_count t_numbercoll;
Begin
  ....
end process_shipping_order
```

When I execute this code I get an error stating that t_numbercoll, t_varchar2coll, and t_numbercoll are undeclared variable. Can you please help me figure out what I am doing wrong. I am using Toad for Oracle. My Oracle version is 10.2.

Regards

Comment: Please, give the full text of code that you executed. These examples have no errors, but you need to use them in right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t_numbercoll`, `t_varchar2coll`, and `t_numbercoll` are the names of your *types*, not variables - so if your procedural code between BEGIN..END (which you still haven't posted) refers to them, Oracle will raise a compilation error.